# Show that $f^{-1}(a)$ is a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a real analytic function with infinitely many zeros. Let $a\neq 0$ be a real number. Show that  $f^{-1}(a)$ is a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem?

Comment: @Ale.P: I have no idea to start.

Comment: It might help you to recall all of the definitions of the terms being used in this question.

Comment: @DanielRust: Really, i have no idea. In fact I understood all the terminology here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: If an analytic function's zero set has a limit point, the function is constantly zero. Use that fact to show that $f^{-1}[\{a\}]$ is a discrete set.

Comment: So any discrete set is a submanifold?

Comment: A zero-dimensional one, yes. Unless its an empty set, sometimes manifolds are assumed to be nonempty. But clearly it is not the case in this exercise. (As $f=\sin$, $a=235$ witness.)

Comment: In which case we can say that this set is finite?

Comment: No, as $f=\sin$, $a=1/6$ witness.